# Reused cell has UIView from previous cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a `tableview` in my view-controller and each `tableview cell` is associated with an audio file.  I'm using custom tableview cells that have a `UIView` inside.  The UIView for each cell has a unique `UIBezierPath` that is stroked in blue.  When the cell is tapped, `didSelectRowForIndexPath` initiates playing the audio file and the blue UIBezierPath is stroked over with a red UIBezierPath in relation to the progress of the audio file.

```
float progress =  playTime/duration;
self.redWave.strokeEnd = self.progress;
```

This is working just fine.  What I noticed is that when I tap the first cell, the audio will start playing and the red path will begin to get stroked - which is suppose to happen, but if I scroll down while this is happening, the 5th cell down from the one I tapped has the same UIBezierPath and it is also stroking the red path over the blue path!  Its clear that the cell is being reused.  Also, this isn't just happening when I tap a cell - the UIBezierPath's of the first 5 cells are replicated in the next set of 5 cells by default when my tableview loads.  I don't know how to get around this.  Any ideas?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString* identifier = @"audioTableCell";

    OSAudioTableCell *cell = [self.audioTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
         cell = [[OSAudioTableCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: identifier];

    }

        //Pull data from NSFetchResultsController
        Recording * recording = [self.managedDocument.frc objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        cell.waveView.minAmpl = [recording.minAmpl floatValue];

        //UIBezierPath Data
        NSData * pathData = recording.waveData;

        //set path for UIView (waveView is custom UIView class)
        cell.waveView.path = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:pathData];
        [cell setImageSize:cell.waveView.bounds.size];

        cell.tag = indexPath.row;

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        //tableCell textfield 
        NSString * track = @"Track";
        NSInteger row = indexPath.row;
        row = [self.managedDocument.frc.fetchedObjects count] - row;
        track = [track stringByAppendingFormat:@" %li",(long)row];
        cell.trackLabel.text = track;
        [cell.textField setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Raleway-SemiBold" size:12]];
        cell.textField.delegate = self;

        if([recording.trackTitle isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            cell.textField.text = track;
        }
        else
        {
            cell.textField.text = recording.trackTitle;

        }

        UIColor * circleColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:107/255.0f green:212/255.0f blue:231/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

        cell.trackIcon.backgroundColor = circleColor;

        [cell.trackIcon.layer setCornerRadius:cell.trackIcon.bounds.size.width/2];

        cell.trackIcon.layer.masksToBounds = YES;


return cell;
```

}

`didSelectRowAtIndexPath` calls the following method in my `tableViewCell` class:

```
-(void) rowSelected2: (NSURL*) url
{

    self.audioPlayer = [OSTablePlayerController getInstance];
    NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [self.audioPlayer playAudio:data];
    self.audioPlayer.isPlayerPlaying = YES;
    self.timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(updateProgress:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:self.timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];

 }
```

Comment: have you tried `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` instead?

Comment: @mckeejm I tried doing `OSAudioTableCell *cell = [self.audioTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
` made no difference :(

Answer (score 7):

Table views are designed to reuse the rows. It's a feature that can improve the performance of your app, especially if your table view has a lot of elements in it.

Since table views reuse their rows, you need to manually clear your rows before they are recycled. If you implemented your cells by creating a UITableViewCell subclass, then you can override its

`- (void)prepareForReuse`

method. This gets called each time a cell is about to be reused, and it is the perfect location for doing any clean up that might need to happen.

Comment: +1 I didn't know about this `prepareForReuse` method. I've always reset my cells just before returning them from `-tableView:cellforRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: The problem with this approach is that if I select a cell and scroll down while the file is still playing and scroll back to the cell I selected, this would result in the red path getting set to zero making it appear as if I never selected the cell.

Comment: What do you mean, "any clean up", specifically.  Can you give any generic example of when you would want to "clean up".  I am having a similar problem to this question and I am not clear the benefit of this.  Thank you.

Comment: @Brosef Your view controller (or whatever handles the cell configuration) will need to keep track of which cells have been selected and how much time has has elapsed for each audio file. That way the red line can be redrawn correctly every time a selected cell shows up on the screen.

Comment: @tpdietz Imagine that each of your table view cells have an image view, and the image displayed by the image view is downloaded from the internet. Before the image has been downloaded, you want to display a some sort of placeholder. For this case, your clean up process might involve canceling any in progress download operations for the cell and resetting its image view's image to the placeholder.

Comment: @martega before I even select a cell, I can see that the second set of 5 cells have the same exact same path as the first set of 5 cells.  For my `prepareForResure` method would I just set the path to nil?

Comment: @Brosef It's hard to say without knowing how you implemented your app, but that might be a good solution. Basically, you should use that method to reset everything to the defaults. If the default path value is nil, then set it to nil in the prepareForReuse method.

Comment: @martega I tried doing  self.waveView.path = nil in `prepareForReuse` but the waveforms are still repeating.  Am I suppose to call `prepareForReuse` manually?

Comment: @Brosef You should never need to call `prepareForReuse` manually. First, you should verify that `prepareForReuse` is being called correctly by setting a break point, or by adding a log statement. If it is being called, then you probably just need to tell iOS to redraw your view, which you can do by calling `setNeedsDisplay` on your cell's contentView.

Comment: @martega under `prepareForReuse` in my custom table view cell class I set the UIView's path to nil, the view itself to nil, then `[self.waveView setNeedsDisplay];`.  I tried varying `setNeedsDisplay` with `layoutIfNeeded` and `layoutSubviews` but the views are still being replicated.

Answer (score 0):

Many apps that play media in tableview cells (e.g. tumblr) stop the playback as the cells are scrolled away (probably using prepareForReuse).

If you want to continue the playback, you'll need to keep all of the state associated with that playback outside of the table cell (in your model) including the playback progress.  Your custom cell should be prepared to indicate playback progress starting at any point (from 0-99%).  When a cell comes into view (in your datasource `cellForRowAtIndexPath`), you'll be required to check your model to see if that cell's media is playing and have it draw the current progress (hopefully it has a method `setProgress:(float)progress` that changes a progress property and tells that bezier drawing view to `setNeedsDisplay`).

This also means that if there's a timer set to check the media playback progress, it's target cannot be the cell, but rather the view controller that maintains the model.

Comment: I have an `NSObject` class called `OSTablePlayerController` that has the audio player and all its functionality (start, stop) as properties.  However, I allocate and initialize it from my table view cell class.  My table view cell class also has the timer that detects the progress.  So I need to move all this to my view controller?

Comment: Yes, and set it's target/action to the view controller.  In there, you'll need to figure out which row in your model is playing and update it's progress (the model needs to keep playback progress since you can't depend on the cells to be around).

Comment: Any idea why the second set of 5 cells have the same UIView path as the first set of 5 cells?